# Laravel PHP Fatal Error: Class 'Table' not found with migrate command

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, migration

I'm using Laravel, and I'm trying to migrate some tables to my DB(phpmyadmin). It was giving me some trouble before, so I eliminated all the rows in the migration table in the DB, so now it has nothing. So I try to run 'php artisan migrate' and I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Table' not found in /var/www/loja/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php on line 301
>   {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Table' not found","file":"/var/www/loja/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php","line":301}}

I don't have any table or class named 'Table'.
Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Can you post what your migration looks like?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I already solved this. I discovered that migration files follow a certain format. 
For example, I had my files like this:
001_create_user_admin_table.php

And I discovered that the format has to be yyyy_mm_dd_hhmmss_name_of_file.php
It has to have those first four arguments, that's why up top it said I couldn't find a Class 'table', because the way I had it before, table was my 5th argument in the file name.

Comment: Saved my day. I did the exact same thing with renaming migrations. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a more helpful error message or something in the documentation that mentioned this!

Answer (score 5):

try to execute this command : `composer dump-autoload`

Ysee